# How to use a mixin-ed method of a class in another mixin of another class

Tags: dart

I have `class B` which has object of `class A` as a member field.
And I want to access the new mixin-ed method of `class A` in the mixin-ed method for `class B`. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=2af929e713c46e9b853aee84f4407007&null_safety=true

```dart
class A {}

class B {
  final A objOfA;
  const B(this.objOfA);
}

mixin MixedA on A {
  void someNewMethod() {
    // do something
  }
}

mixin MixedB on B {
  void someMethod() {
    objOfA.someNewMethod(); // <-- error
  }
}
```

Comment: Class `A` does not have any `someNewMethod`. Are you perhaps confusing mixins with extension methods: `extension NewOnA on A { void someNewMethod() { ... } }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mixin MixedB on B` means that classes that use `MixedB` are known only to derive from `B`.  Class `B` provides no guarantee that its `objOfA` member is an instance of `MixedA`.  Some of your options:

- Make `B` require that `objOfA` is a `MixedA` by declaring it as: `final MixedA objOfA;`
- If you can't unconditionally declare `objOfA` to be a `MixedA`, perhaps you could make `B` generic and make `MixedB` require a specialized base type:

  ```dart
  class B<DerivedA extends A> {
    final DerivedA objOfA;
    const B(this.objOfA);
  }

  mixin MixedB on B<MixedA> {
    // ...
  }
  ```
- Make `MixedB` perform a runtime check:

  ```dart
  mixin MixedB on B {
    void someMethod() {
      final objOfA = this.objOfA;
      if (objOfA is MixedA) {
        objOfA.someNewMethod();
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- If you can personally guarantee that `objOfA` will always be a `MixedA` when `MixedB` is used (but you can't provide a static, compile-time guarantee), you could make `MixedB` override `objOfA` and cast it to a `MixedB`:

  ```dart
  mixin MixedB on B {
    @override
    MixedA get objOfA => super.objOfA as MixedA;

    void someMethod() {
      objOfA.someNewMethod();
    }
  }
  ```